# How do I to create a div loading located front of everything?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div to work as an ajax loader. On my website I have some modals and this one displays behind them all. I want it stay on front of everything.

How could I to achieve this ?

Trying

```
/** loader */
#div_loading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 11;
    background-color: #FFF;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: .50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=65);
    background-image: url(../Imagens/ajaxloader.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 120px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can u create a JSFiddle please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually just a matter of increasing the `z-index`. Try setting it to 99999 or something.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the modal a [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) less than that of the loader, i.e., less than 11 in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You should see this link to know more about z-index https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

```
#div_loading {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #FFF;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        opacity: .50;
        filter: alpha(opacity=65);
        background-image: url(../Imagens/ajaxloader.gif);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: 120px;
        display: none;
    }
```